# Cannot set the value of paragraph as a new variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I am trying to get a value of paragraph and set it as a var / const / let

The code I am trying to get the value of paragraph

```
<p id="serial_number">232323323232</p>
```

This works:

```
$('#serial_number').html();
```

returns value of

```
"232323323232"
```

But when I am trying to store the result as var:

```
var number = $('#serial_number').html();
```

returns value of

```
"undefined"
```

How to achieve this result?

```
var number = 232323323232
```

Comment: try `.text()`  ..

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely doing an asynchronous operation, which will make jQuery return undefined because it doesn't have access to the DOM node yet. Works here, so I would advise you to check:

1. When you are invoking this
2. Your dependencies being up to date
3. If the p tag is rendered on the server and sent as a result to the client.

If the result is rendered on the server, you could use Mutation Observer ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver ) to watch the tag until the content is rendered in it, and then update it. Similar to how `document.ready` in jQuery works, but it will wait until the tag has changed.

https://codepen.io/evenstensberg/pen/oOoMmV#0

Comment: Now I can achieve the result by doing $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){     },4000);  }); Is this the only way?

Comment: No. You should use a mutation observer for this to wait until the p tag is loaded in the DOM. Given as the link I provided

Answer (score 0):

To make it a number, use `text` and `parseInt`:

```js
var number = parseInt($("#serial_number").text());
console.log(number);
console.log(typeof number);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<p id="serial_number">232323323232</p>
```

Comment: No it's not - press `Run code snippet` above @Ratna.

Answer (score 0):

Try **`.innerHTML`**

```
var number = $('#serial_number').innerHTML;
```